# Find all roots of the polynomial equation $p(p(x)) - x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Let $p(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial such that for distinct reals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $$p(\alpha)=\alpha\ \&\ p(\beta)=\beta$$
Show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the following equation $$p(p(x))-x=0$$
Also find the remaining roots.

The first part was very simple to prove, in order to find the remaining roots, I assumed $t$ to be a root of the second equation with $p(t)=u.$ Hence it immediately follows that $u$ is also the root of the second equation with $p(u)=t$. Now the task is to find such $u$ and $t$. We have
$$at^2+bt+c=u \ \ \ \ (1)$$ and $$au^2+bu+c=t\ \ \ (2)$$
Thus, taking (1) - (2) and cancelling $u-t$ we get
$$u+t=\frac{-(1+b)}{a}$$ Now, taking $u^2*(1) - t^2*(2)$ and cancelling $u-t$ again, we get $$ut=\frac{1+b+ac}{a^2}$$
With this, we see that $u$ and $t$ are the roots of the following equation
$$a^2x^2+a(1+b)x+(1+b+ac)=0$$
And thus the roots can be computed using the quadratic formula.

First of all, I want to know whether my answer is correct or not, as the book that I use does not provide any answer to this problem, and if it is incorrect, I would like to know the correct answer.

If my answer is correct, can the answer be better in anyway? (as I only came up with an equation for the roots... and writing down the final answer using the quadratic formula looks crazy!!)

Thanks for any answers!!

Edit: Here I have assumed $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: The linear polynomial $r(x)=\alpha\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}+\beta\frac{x-\beta}{\alpha-\beta}$ satisfies $r(\alpha)=\beta$ and $r(\beta)=\alpha$. Then $p(x)-r(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial that vanishes at $\alpha$ and at $\beta$. Therefore, $p(x)-r(x)=m(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, where $m$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: Yes..but how do we further the solution?

Comment: Once you have $p$ you can compute $p(p(x))-x$ and divide it by $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ and compute the roots of the quotient.

Comment: Well, in what I wrote above I assumed that the given equations were $p(\alpha)=\beta$ and $p(\beta)=\alpha$. In your case, $r(x)=x$.

Comment: PurpleOverGreen..I don’t quite get you..  could you please post the full answer?

Comment: How did you understand the answer that you chose and not this? r(x) is a linear polynomial that satisfies the given equations for $p$. When you subtract it from $p$ you get a quadratic polynomial that vanishes at $\alpha$ and at $\beta$. Therefore, it has the form $m(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. Then $p(x)=r(x)+m(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. Once you have $p$ compute the equation $p(p(x))-x$ and solve it by factoring out the known factors $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ and solving the remaining quadratic.

Comment: Yea, I understood now..thanks for the answer PurpleOverGreen!

Comment: I hadn’t seen the comment where you told r(x) = x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $q(x)= p(x)-x$, then given equation is equivalent to $$q(q(x)+x)+q(x)=0$$

Since $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are roots for $q$ we have $$q(x)=c(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$ where $c\ne 0$, so $$ c(q(x)+x-\alpha )(q(x)+x-\beta)+c(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$$

so $$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\Big(\color{\red}{(cx-c\alpha+1)(cx-c\beta+1)+1}\Big)=0$$

So you need to solve the red equation...

Comment: What about my method? It it right or wrong?...I mean the equation that I got

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with $t$ and $u$. In fact I find it very nice idea. But I don't know how you found next two equations. If they are correct you are on the spot.

Comment: I’ll edit my question to show that.. could you please stay online to verify it?

Comment: Yes, everything is OK

Comment: I have edited my question to include the steps..

Comment: I have caluculated it my self and it is OK

Comment: Okay..thanks a lot for your help!